# Demonstrate estimates do not depend on linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations, proof-explanation, log-likelihood

Demonstrate maximum likelihood estimates do not depend on linear transformations  prove that the likelihood functions $f(\tilde{y}/x)$ and $f(y/x)$ coincide.

Given:

$\tilde{y}$ = Ty = T Hx+ T v ,

T is a square non-singular $m x m$,

v is a Gaussian random vector.

My first idea was:

The estimate $x^{m}$ is calculated by selecting the value of maximizing with the **necessary maximum condition** for equation 
\begin{align}\label{1}
f(y/x) = ln\Big( p(y/x)  \Big)=- \frac{1}{2} (y-Hx)^{T} R^{-1} (y-Hx):
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
\frac{d }{dx} \Big(ln \quad \mathit{p}(y/x) \Big) \Big\vert_{ {\hat{x}^{m}(y)} }  = 0          \\
\frac{d \Big(  - \frac{1}{2} (y-Hx)^{T} R^{-1} (y-Hx)  \Big)}{dx} \Big\vert_{ {\hat{x}^{m}(y)} } = 0  \\
-\frac{1}{2} \Big( -H^{T} R^{-1} y + H^{T} R^{-1} H \hat{x}^{m} \Big)  = 0\\
H^{T} R^{-1} H \hat{x}^{m}  = H^{T} R^{-1} y        \\ 
H \hat{x}^{m}  = y                \\ 
\rightarrow  \hat{x}^{m}  = H^{-1}y          \\ 
\text{or} \qquad \hat{x}^{m} = (H^{T} R^{-1} H)^{-1} H^{T} R^{-1} y
\end{align*}
This same expression follows directly for equation with $\tilde{y}$ = Ty : 
\begin{align} \label{2}
f( \tilde{y}/x) = ln\Big( p(\tilde{y}/x)  \Big)= - \frac{1}{2} (Ty-Hx)^{T} R^{-1} (Ty-Hx): 
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
\frac{d }{dx} \Big(ln \quad \mathit{p}(\tilde{y}/x) \Big) \Big\vert_{ {\hat{x}^{m}(y)} }  = 0 \\
\frac{d \Big(  - \frac{1}{2} (Ty-Hx)^{T} R^{-1} (Ty-Hx)  \Big)}{dx} \Big\vert_{ {\hat{x}^{m}(y)} }  = 0  \\
-\frac{1}{2} \Big( -H^{T} R^{-1} Ty + H^{T} R^{-1} H \hat{x}^{m} \Big)  = 0     \\
H^{T} R^{-1} H \hat{x}^{m}  = H^{T} R^{-1} Ty            \\ 
\hat{x}^{m} = H^{-1} Ty                    \\
\text{with $\tilde{y}=Ty$} \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \\
\rightarrow \hat{x}^{m} = H^{-1} \tilde{y} \\
\text{or} \qquad \hat{x}^{m} = (H^{T} R^{-1} H)^{-1} H^{T} R^{-1} \tilde{y}
\end{align*}

It is a bit unclear because results for equation 1 and 2 are not the same.
Because: $\hat x^{m}_1 - \hat x^{m}_2 = \left(H^TR^{-1}H\right)^{-1}H^TR^{-1}\left(y- Ty\right) \neq 0.$

How can I show that the estimate does not depend on linear transformation ?
I suppose here is a little skill applied.

Comment: is there an assumption missing here in the task? 
Or proove it like $f( \tilde{y}/x) \cdot \big( f(y/x) \big)^{-1} = 1$ ?

Comment: \begin{equation}  
f( \tilde{y}/x) = f(y/x) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}  
 - \frac{1}{2} (Ty-Hx)^{T} R^{-1} (Ty-Hx) = - \frac{1}{2} (y-Hx)^{T} R^{-1} (y-Hx) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}  
(Ty-Hx)^{T} R^{-1} (Ty-Hx) = (y-Hx)^{T} R^{-1} (y-Hx) 
\end{equation} 
.... 

\begin{align*}  
x^{T}H^{T}R^{-1} (Ty - y) = y^{T} \big( R^{-1}(Hx-y) -T^{T}R^{-1}(Hx-Ty) \big)
\end{align*} 

and now what i make to do ?